# SPARQL 'concat' error

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm getting an error message on `concat` in SPARQL (Servlet in Netbeans). Could you please suggest any solution to this problem?

```
PREFIX table:<http://www.daltons.com#>
SELECT ?name
WHERE{
  ?Author table:hasFirstName ?FN. 
  ?Author table:hasLastName ?LN. 
  bind (concat(str(?FN),str(?LN)) as ?name) 
}
```

> Lexical error at line 1, column 132.  Encountered: "(" (40), after :
>   "bind"

Comment: What version of Jena (and ARQ) is this?  The query as written validates with current ARQ code so it may be a case of an outdated version.  For reference the current release is 2.10.0

Comment: it might be the space " " between `bind` and the "(".

Comment: this query doesn't give any exception in my machine

Comment: I used 2.8.1 version of jena then I considered your advice and I found to download 2.8.8 of jena(couldnt find 2.10.0 version jena's library) but I have "Encountered " "as" "as "" at line 1, column 160." Errors at this time...

Comment: @sedos17 Where are you downloading from? SourceForge? 2.8.8 is still very out of date.  Latest Jena releases may be found at jena.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

```
"PREFIX table:<http://www.example.com#>" 
+"SELECT " 
+ "(CONCAT(?FN, \" \",COALESCE(?MD,\"\"),\" \", ?LN) AS ?name)" 
+"WHERE{" 
+"?Author table:hasFirstName ?FN. " 
+"OPTIONAL{?Author table:hasMiddleName ?MD}." 
+"?Author table:hasLastName ?LN} "; 

Finally found the right answer with this code and used 2.8.8 version arq of jena . Thanks for your interest and suggestions.
```

Comment: ARQ 2.8.8 is very out of date, latest releases may be obtained from http://jena.apache.org